# What does this line means "If ds.tables("corresponding table name").Row.Count <> 0 Then"

Tags: vb.net

What does this line means  "If ds.tables("corresponding table name").Row.Count <> 0 Then"

```
If ds.tables("corresponding table name").Row.Count <> 0 Then
    (Form Name).show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
    MsgBox("Login Failed")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

That line is presumably validating a login by retrieving user records from a database that match a particular user name and password.  If the `DataTable` in that `DataSet` has more than zero rows in it then there was at least one matching user record, so the login was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there must be a an `SQL` query which have been executed and its result would be fetched in `DataSet` object. Thus the query might be checking for valid username and password in database, if number of rows resulted by that query is more than 1, that means there is a record which is matching to given username and password and we must allow that user to login. So by above given syntax they might have fetched the query result into DataSet object, now `DataSet` object may contain more than 1 `DataTable`, and those `DataTable` hold the number of rows we got into result by executing the `SQL` query. Thus its simply trying to check that given `DataTable` has more than 0 rows? if it is then it must allow to login or else it will show as "Login Failed".

Answer (score 0):

Presumably there has also been a `SQL SELECT` statement executed before this code appears and then the results from it have been filled into a `DataSet`. The query would have been something along the lines of

```
"SELECT * FROM [tblUsers] WHERE [Username] = ? AND [Password] = ?"
```

With parameters for `txtUsername` and `txtPassword`, or something like this.

```
If ds.tables("corresponding table name").Row.Count <> 0 Then
```

This line is a conditional instruction. It's saying "If `table x` in `DataSet y` does not have 0 rows (ie, 1 or more), then go to the next instruction.

```
(Form Name).Show()
```

So, if the previous line has conditioned to `True` and there is at least 1 row in `table x`, then it will load and show `Form z`

```
Me.Hide()
```

And in turn, hides the current form from the user.

```
Else
```

Otherwise, if the first line conditions to `False` and there are no rows in `table x`, then jump to this line.

```
MsgBox("Login Failed")
```

Shows a `MsgBox` alerting the user that the log on has failed

```
End If
```

Ends the condition.